# php doctrine last identifier issue

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm running in to the issue below when trying to run the following:

```
$store = new Store();
$store->url =$this->form_validation->set_value('website');
$store->save();
$store_id = $store->identifier();


Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Connection_Exception' with message 'Couldn't get last insert identifier.' in /home/yummm/public_html/system/application/plugins/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Connection/UnitOfWork.php:932 Stack trace: #0 /home/yummm/public_html/system/application/plugins/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Connection/UnitOfWork.php(632): Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->_assignIdentifier(Object(Category_store_assn)) #1 /home/yummm/public_html/system/application/plugins/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Connection/UnitOfWork.php(562): Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->processSingleInsert(Object(Category_store_assn)) #2 /home/yummm/public_html/system/application/plugins/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Connection/UnitOfWork.php(81): Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->insert(Object(Category_store_assn)) #3 /home/yummm/public_html/system/application/plugins/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Record.php(1691): Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->saveGraph(Object(Category_store_assn)) #4 /home/yummm/public_html/system/application/controllers/auth.php(375): Doctrine_Reco in /home/yummm/public_html/system/application/plugins/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Connection/UnitOfWork.php on line 932
```

When I echo $store_id, it seems to be grabbing the last id without any issues.  Any idea why this error keeps coming up even though the ID is passing correctly?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the column definition itself isn't set up as auto_increment. Check the table definition with: (assuming MySQL)

```
DESCRIBE table_name;
```

and make sure that your ID field is flagged as auto_increment. If it's not Doctrine will try to get the last identifier for the table but will fail because only auto_increment columns response to MySQL's LAST_INSERT_ID() function.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me with Doctrine 1.2. This one didn't work:

```
    $this->hasColumn('id', 'int', null, array(
    'primary'       => true,
    'autoincrement' => true
));
```

And this one did:

```
    $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
      'type' => 'integer',
      'length' => 4,
      'unsigned' => true,
      'primary' => true,
      'autoincrement' => true,
));
```

Not sure why the difference, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the problem is in 'autoincrement' => true for primary key field inside hasColumn().
If I set 'autoincrement' => false, the problem is gone.

But the primary key field of that table is an autoincremented field. And it is still strange, that on the others computers there are no any errors. The application and databases are the same on all that computers.

Answer (score 0):

And now i have found that it is because lastInsertId() method of PDO object returns 0. 
So, suppose, the problem is in PDO driver and it is not the Doctrine bug. 
Need to reinstall PHP or PDO extension. 
Also, see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33618.

Comment: this bug report has been closed for five years. The PDO drivers should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your ID from Store table is probably not set to autoincrement. In this case, you have to 'tell' it to doctrine record model by used mixed option parameter in the hasColumn function:

```
$this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 11, array(
    'primary' => true,
    'autoincrement' => false) 
    );
```

Or set your ID autoincrement if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I my case it was PDO driver bug.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you overwrote the `setTableDefinition()` method, and now there is no `hasColum()` call for your `id` attribute.